# core data - relationships, fetching and inserting

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm using `CoreData` for the first time in one of my project. My table involves `FOREIGN KEYS` and since `CoreData` doesn't support `FOREIGN KEYS`, I'm having some issues.

Below is the structure of my tables.

[image: Table Structure]

My Problem is the `establishment` attribute.The establishment attribute is supposed to hold the name of a particular facility from the `Facilities` table. However, since it's a relationship, `Xcode` expects a `Facility` rather than just a name of a facility (`NSString`).

Is this possible, or am I just mixing up `FOREIGN KEYS` with `RELATIONSHIPS` in `CoreData`? How would I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A relationship is *not* a property, so it does not have a type. In the model editor you add a relationship explicitly.

From your diagram, I see that you did not set the inverse relationship. There needs to be a corresponding relationship from `name` to the `Assessors` entity. (Set the "Destination" to `Assessors` in the model editor.)

I would also suggest to rename a few items.

First, use singular: `Assessor`, `Facility`. These are objects (comparable to classes), not tables.

Second, because your `name` attribute refers to an assessor, call it `assessor`, and similarly call its reverse relationship `facilities` (it is a to-many relationship in this direction, so the plural is appropriate).

If you need the name of the assessor of a facility, you use

```
facility.assessor.name
```

This should make it obvious why you do not need foreign keys. Indeed, I would urge you to think that it is not Core Data that does not support foreign keys, but that it is the traditional relational databases that do not support relationships!